# How can I input some standard values, whereafter going on

Tags: python, shell, oop, input

I'm setting up a game 'Battleship' in Python using OOP. The initializing part is ready, like setting up the boats where they like them. (For each boat, they have to give its starting position and direction.) To test the rest of the program, it would be nice if I could just make a file with all inputs (example: 
A2
h
B7
v
etc.)
and after that, going on with the program, like asking where I would like to shoot my first cannonball.

Is there a possibility to automate this first part?

```
def starting_up(self, own, opponent):
        """Initialize own board."""
        os.system('cls')
        ship_list = [("Destroyer", 2), ("Submarine", 3), ("Cruiser", 3), ('Battleship', 4), ('Carrier', 5)]

        input(own.name + ", press Enter if you're ready. ")
        for ship in reversed(ship_list):
            succesful = False
            while not succesful:
                #os.system('cls')
                own.draw_boards(own, opponent)
                position = insert_position(own, ship) 
                direction = insert_direction(own, ship)

                if check_if_possible(own, position, direction, ship):
                    succesful = True
                    own.draw_ship(position, direction, ship)
                else:
                    print("\nIt's not possible to place a ship here. Please chose an other location.\n")
                    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: if you use `input()` to get data then you can use `python script.py <data.txt` and `input()` will get all information only from file.

Comment: other method is to separated `input()` from rest of code - put in separated function ie. `get_input` - so you could replace `get_input` with other function which get data from file.

Comment: in python you can assign one function to name of other function  `input = my_input` (without `()`) and now when you use `input` then it will run `my_input`. And in `my_input` you can return data from file.